# Using old MySQL data folder on new MySQL installation

Tags: mysql

If I could have made a proper `SQL dump/backup` I would have, but `OS` gave out and could only log into `SafeMode`, where I couldn't start the `MySQL server`. Therefore, I could only manually backup the file directories.

- I have a saved file copy of C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
- I have a saved file copy of C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

I'm now running on a new installation of `Windows` and trying to start this old server up for a few minutes so I can log on from `Workbench` and make a proper `SQL database dump` which will I `import` on a new `MySQL` installation later.

Consequently, moving the mentioned files in their respective locations - `Program Files` and `ProgramData`.

Opening up `PowerShell` (with Admin rights) and doing:

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0" --console
```

and I get a few **hundred** lines on the screen that contain the following:

```
2020-04-10T05:28:56.725818Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2020-04-10T05:28:56.734460Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_undo_001' Page [page id: space=4294967279, page number=5] log sequence number 1339677380 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 19081380.
```

Followed by:

```
2020-04-10T05:28:56.740834Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
2020-04-10T05:28:56.757259Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2020-04-10T05:28:56.769215Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2020-04-10T05:28:57.695386Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-10T05:28:57.765911Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-10T05:28:57.926850Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Great, at least its running.

I can now `connect` but no `databases`.

- What can I do / how should I proceed to successfully get those databases back temporarily?

**UPDATE:**

Removed the innodb_undo_001 and innodb_undo_002 files from the Data directory and relaunched.

Getting this:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin> .\mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console                                                               2020-04-10T05:55:29.555478Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-04-10T05:55:29.558313Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 3028
2020-04-10T05:55:31.394427Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012351] [InnoDB] Tablespace 1, name 'sys/sys_config', file '.\sys\sys_config.ibd' is missing!
2020-04-10T05:55:32.808645Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-10T05:55:32.856154Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-10T05:55:32.898055Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

***Running but no databases present.***

Comment: Have you tried putting this `[mysqld] innodb_force_recovery = 1` (or other value) into your my.ini (or whatever it's called) as suggested [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)? I think (not an expert anymore - used to do a lot of MySQL stuff) but the idea is that you gradually incremement the number until you get **something**?

Comment: @Vérace Yes, tried that. Nothing. I don't understand how it can be corrupted since they seem fine and I just did a manual copy of the entire directory. 1 hr early everything was working fine. I'm pretty certain the files are fine - there must be another problem for why they're not getting 'pulled' in. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You could try the Percona [data recovery tool](https://www.percona.com/tools) - follow links - I think you have to download the entire toolkit. I've never used it, but Percona are the dog's for anything to do with MySQL! Please let me know how you get on! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Vérace Hey there, sorry about the delay, Easter and all. Hope you are well. Thank you for suggesting Percona but I'm on Windows and I see that's only for Linux. I'll keep looking for way to get this working, if not, I'll eventually try out Linux so I can use Percona. Thanks!